# Mostrar cantidad de numeradores = 3 en un struct

Tags: c, struct

Tengo el siguiente programa en C el usuario ingresa numeradores y denominadores en un struct de enteros y se debe desplegar la cantidad de numeradores con valor "3":

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 using namespace std;

 //Se declara un array de tipo struct

 typedef struct fraccion

 {

  int numerador, denominador;

 }fraccion;

 //fin de declaracion de tipo struct llamado "fraccion" y con variables 
 "numerador y denominador"


  int main()
  {
   //Array de 3 fracciones

  fraccion arrFraccion[3];

   int i = 0;
   int Contador=0;

   int num = 1;

   while (num == 1)

   {

   int seleccion; //declara una variable de tipo entera llamada "seleccion"               para el menu mas abajo

   printf("\nPresione 1 para ingresar una fraccion\n"); //opcion 1 del menu para igresar una fraccion
   scanf("%d", &seleccion); //Se ingresa el valor

if(seleccion == 1)

 {  //Inicio del if

for (i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        printf("\nIngrese su fraccion, numerador seguido de denominador\n");
        scanf("%d %d",&arrFraccion[i].numerador, &arrFraccion[i].denominador);//Usuario ingresa valores

      if (&arrFraccion.numerador==3) //si el valor de numerador es = a 3
        {
                Contador ++; //incrementa el contador

         } //fin del if del contador

       i++; //Incrementa el indice
       }
       printf ("La cantidad de numeradores con el numero 3 son: ", Contador);
   }
return 0;
 }
}
```

Mi duda es: por que no me muestra la cantidad de numeradores con el numero 3?

Solo me despliega vacio:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos y muchas gracias!

Comment: Parece código C, efectivamente. Pero la cabecera `<iostream>` es C++. Dado que no parece que estés usando ninguna de sus utilidades, yo la quitaría.

Comment: Además de que la cabecera `<iostream>` no está disponible en C, la cláusula `using namespace std` es incompatible con C ya que éste no dispone de espacios de nombres ¿**seguro** que estás programando en C?

Answer (score 4):

Tu problema es este:

```
if (&arrFraccion.numerador==3) //si el valor de numerador es = a 3
```

Esa línea no comprueba si el valor del numerador es tres; comprueba si la dirección de memoria de el elemento `numerador` de la instancia `arrFraccion` es tres; lo cuál nunca será cierto.

Además esa instrucción tampoco compila ya que `arrFraccion` es una formación<sup>1</sup>, el nombre de la formación es equivalente a un puntero al primer elemento, por lo tanto no podrías usar el operador punto (`.`) para acceder al elemento `numerador`: deberías usar el operador flecha (`->`).

Esta sería una posible versión de tu código corregido:

```
if (arrFraccion[i].numerador==3) //si el valor de numerador es = a 3
```

Observa que no he usado la flecha; esto es porque no estoy usando el nombre de la formación si no que la estoy indizando con el operador corchetes (`[]`) que devuelve una instancia, no un puntero.

---

1. También conocida como arreglo, o en inglés: array.

Comment: No debería ser sin el `&`?

Comment: Toda la razón @Mateo

Answer (score 1):

Falta indicar donde quieres imprimir la cantidad agregando `%d`:

```
printf ("La cantidad de numeradores con el numero 3 son: %d", Contador);
```

Además debes corregir el if que cuenta los tres.

Debes borrar el `&` porque indica que estas revisando el valor de la direción no la dirección.

Debes agregar el numero del elemento dentro del array al que quieres acceder.

```
if (arrFraccion[i].numerador==3) //si el valor de numerador es = a 3
```